# Java swing: UI not repainted correctly (white)

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am encountering a problem in my applications UI Client where in certain conditions (user logins to locked desktop account) the UI elements (frames, drop down lists) are not displayed correctly. 
It happens on  Windows 10 64bit Version 1709. 
I believe this is a low-level issue on interface with the system or with graphic card driver. 
I have already tried setting  sun.java2d.d3d=false and many other approaches (updating drivers, changing power management properties) with no success.
I have also monitored threads (none are being locked) and I do updates in invokeLater so this is not related to UI freezes due to prolonged calls.

The issue only occurs on a few machines while others with the same windows version have no such problems.
There isn't any particular action in the UI that user can perform that would trigger the issue, it always seems to be some external cause that I try to pinpoint.

What I am looking for is an idea how can I debug on lower level or even on the operating system side to see what is failing. 
Is there a way for me to log any graphics related events that come from the OS (like changes in Look and Feel that are passed down to JVM)

Thank you for help

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"Thank you for help"* Thank you for your question. .. Wait. What is your question?

Comment: I cannot post code because I am unable to reproduce the issue locally and the client is quite complex otherwise. My question is not about the code fix but rather: what are the ways to perform deeper logging and debugging of JVM or conflicts bewteen JVM and system since what I believe is happening: system changes some graphic settings (or sleeps the graphic card when screen is locked) and my app is not recovering from that. I would like to log events sent to JVM (or Swing libraries) that lead to this

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not find the answer how to log such events I have found a solution to the problem:
When starting a UI java application, start it with java instead of javaw. This way some deeper exceptions that are not logged by log4j will be visible, in my case it is:
https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6429812

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTableHeaderUI$XPDefaultRenderer.paint(WindowsTableHeaderUI.java:171)
        at javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(CellRendererPane.java:151)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.paintCell(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:710)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.paint(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:652)
        at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
        at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)